# How to find max of selected row based on column date

Tags: python, pandas

Data frame below. I'd like to find the max value of a row based on a specified date. For example i'd like to find max of row where date = 2018-01-05

```
 Index  Date        A        B       C
    0   2018-01-01  10.751026  11.208558  10.759246
    1   2018-01-02  10.780758  11.026139  10.821861
    2   2018-01-03  10.941532  11.244213  10.931028
    3   2018-01-04  10.829012  11.307521  10.998156
    4   2018-01-05  10.863556  11.255390  10.967386
    5   2018-01-08  10.906152  11.383926  10.924383
```

Comment: Please show us your attempt and the expected output.

Comment: Welcome, Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for sharing more details.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this

```
df[df.Date == "2018-01-05"][["A","B","C"]].iloc[0].max()
```

Answer (score 0):

if your data its in a array, you can sort a row then pop it, for Example:

`data_in_row=[row[2:]]
data_in_row.sort()
print(data_in_row.pop())`

but IDK how you make that array...
cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
df[df['Date'] == '2018-01-05'][['A','B', 'C']].max(1)
```